# Count the number of columns which have values among 70 - Access 2000?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 70 columns in my table and it is mostly empty. I want to remove columns which do not have a single value. The problem is, the table has 18000 rows so, scrolling manually is stupid.

I tired with Expression and a Select query, but I see the expression can accept limited number of characters, i.e not enough space to cover all 70 columns.

Here is what I tried:

```
Format(IIf([t4k1],[t4k1],""), "00") & " " & Format(IIf([t4k2],[t4k2],""), "00") & " " &
Format(IIf([t4k3],[t4k3],""), "00") & " " & Format(IIf([t4k4],[t4k4],""), "00") & " " &
Format(IIf([t4k5],[t4k5],""), "00") & " " & Format(IIf([t4k6],[t4k6],""), "00") & " " &
Format(IIf([t4k7],[t4k7],""), "00") & " " & Format(IIf([t4k8],[t4k8],""), "00") & " " &
Format(IIf([t4k9],[t4k9],""), "00") & " " & Format(IIf([t4k10],[t4k10],""), "00") & " " &
Format(IIf([t4k11],[t4k11],""), "00") & " " & Format(IIf([t4k12],[t4k12],""), "00") & " " &
Format(IIf([t4k13],[t4k13],""), "00") & " " & Format(IIf([t4k14],[t4k14],""), "00") & " " &
Format(IIf([t4k15],[t4k15],""), "00") & " " & Format(IIf([t4k16],[t4k16],""), "00")
```

As you can see, the table has 70 columns, t4k1, t4k2, t4k3, ... t4k70

Here is how the table looks like:

[image: empty columns access 2000]

How can I check all 70 columns properly, is it with VBA code?

How would the code look like?

Or is there better way?

Comment: This looks like very un-normalised data. It shouldn't be stored in this way.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the 70 columns should contain 1 where in the row there is some value between 1 and 70. So If a certain column contains value 43, than the right way would be the column 43 to contain 1. The same applies for all other values between 1 and 70 anywhere in these 70 columns :)

Comment: There should only be 3 columns. The UniqueID for the row, A column storing the Kx number and the value. You then only store values that exist, and your query becomes simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `DCount()` in a loop. E.g.

```
Sub PrintEmptyColumns()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 70
        Debug.Print i, DCount("*", "CPA_foo", "Nz(t4k" & i & ", '') <> ''")
    Next i

End Sub
```

If it prints (Ctrl+G opens the direct window)

```
x     0
```

then column `t4k<x>` has zero rows with values.